# When pushing to GitHub through VSCode it does not push parent directory but instead one of the folders within it, any idea how to fix this?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I am fairly new to using githubs commit/push features and seem to have run into an issue. These are the steps I took and the issues I have.

-I set up my github repository and copied the link to the repository
-I added the remote repository in VSCode and pasted the link to the repository in it.
-When I go to push changes it seems to work fine but when I check the repository it seems that only one of the two folders within the parent directory is pushed and the parent directory is no where to be seen

I attached two images where you can see my project in VSCode with the parent directory cryptosinodotgg and the two subdirectories cryptosino-react-app and cryptosino-solidity. When I push to github as seen in the other image it is only pushing the folder cryptosino-react-app. Any idea how to fix this? Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I want to add that when I make changes to files in the folder that is not being included, it does not give me the ability to commit these changes like I can do with the react-app folder.

[Image 1 of project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5foWG.png)

[Image 2 of what is being pushed to github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45A8d.png)

Comment: `git push` never pushes folders or files. It pushes *commits*. The commits then *contain* files (which live in folders when extracted from some commit), but the key here is that you either get the entire commit—the full archive of all files—or nothing. There's never any case where you get just some part of some commit. If you got a new commit that has only six files in it, those are the six files that are in that commit. Every commit has a full copy of every file, because every commit *is* a complete archive.

Comment: @torek thank you for the input, when I change files in the folder that is not being pushed it does not give me an option to commit those changes, opposed to file changes in the included folder giving me the option to commit changes. Also, if I right click on the source control it shows the included folder with a check mark next to it but does not show the parent folder. I am not sure why this is. I added images to the original question aswell as I forgot to do that originally.

Comment: When you mention right-click (or any mouse operation) you've immediately moved away from *Git itself* to *some sort of GUI*. That introduces a new layer of things-that-can-go-wrong. I see this is tagged with VS as well; I know nothing of VS and don't know if that might add more problems here. If you drop to the command line, though, you can query Git itself directly, and avoid having the extra layer of who-knows-what inserted...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer by running git init within the parent directory opposed to going through the VSCode GUI. I then added the remote path using the VSCODE GUI and when I commit all files and push it pushed the entire project.